# How to delete a Fetch Request in XCode 4

Tags: core-data, xcode4

I'm a new user of the data model editor in XCode 4.  How do I delete a Fetch Request which I don't want?  It was difficult to figure out how to add one (click and hold the "Create Entity" button!).  But now that I've created one, I can't for the life of me figure out how to get rid of it.

I'd also appreciated pointers to a good tutorial on building predicates.  eg something which answer how do you test if the year in a date attribute == something and similar questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select the fetch request.
2. Hit delete or backspace.

Enjoy.

*PS: Instead of 2. <strike>you can also choose Delete from the Edit menu</strike>.

Remarkably, this command has been around since 1984. ;-)*

As for your other question: check out Apple's [Predicate Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/predicates.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001789).
To search for a year in a date you do something like

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
   @"date > %@ AND date < %@", janFirstYear1, janFirstYear2];
```

Comment: I too, thought that the Delete key and Edit->Delete were the same thing.  In this case, however, it turns out that Edit->Delete deletes the entire data model!  Even if you have clicked to select the predicate.

Comment: OK, sorry for that - I hope you could undo it. I also hope the hint was helpful (consider accepting the answer).

Comment: No need to undo - deleting the entire data model is serious enough that Xcode puts up a warning/confirmation dialog so I never actually deleted anything.  I'd love to accept your answer but can't see how to do that.  Regarding the date comparison.  I suppose I need to manufacture a date which corresponds to microsecond#1 of Jan 1 of the year, and another which corresponds to the last microsecond of Dec 31, then use >= and <= comparisons.